# Where Does Azure Functions Store Logs And How Can I View Them?

Tags: java, azure-functions

Whilst my Azure Function app is running I can stream the logs and see everything I need to.

Later on the log stream is empty, probably because it is a stream of live logs and not a log viewer.

Where are the logs stored and how do I see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created your functions app you should have also linked it to an [Application Insights workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring)- this is where logs are stored. If you aren't sure which workspace it is, then you can usually find the connection string in the app settings.

Each functions's invocation logs should also link to the relevant data in App Insights- that is a good place to start if you aren't familiar with how to query AI logs.

[image]

Which table the data is stored in depends on the information that you are looking for- errors will be in the exceptions table for example. It is worth noting that Functions makes use of the customEvents and customMetrics tables quite heavily so there will be a quite a bit of useful data landing in those two tables.